# Custom Control "fileDownload", how to have different date for each file

Tags: xpages

I am using a "document library" (template: StdXLWebXDocLib). When I use the Custom Control "fileDownload", I would like to know if is it possible to have a creation date and modification date for each file instead of the same date for all.

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known issue with File Download control.
IBM SPR [LO61249](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO61249): is already submitted and it has been identified as programming bug. No fixes are available for this.